# add custom field prestashop customer

Tags: php, prestashop, custom-fields, prestashop-1.7

Hi I am relatively new to prestashop and wondering if someone could direct me towards a right place.

Basically, I am after adding a new custom field to the create_account page.

I was initially hack fixing the issue, but I know that once prestashop is updated all of the changes to core files will be overwritten.

I have began to do my changes to the AdminCustomerController.php
as below.(Also the field I am trying to add is the Nature of Business)

```
class AdminCustomersController extends AdminCustomersControllerCore {

    public function renderForm($id = null)
    {

        $this->fields_form = array(
            'legend' => array(
                'title' => $this->trans('Customer', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
                'icon' => 'icon-user'
            ),
            'input' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'prefix' => '',
                    'label' => $this->trans('Practice', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
                    'name' => 'practice',
                    'col' => '4',
                    'autocomplete' => false
                ),
                array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->trans('Nature of Business', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
                    'name' => 'nature_enquiry',
                    'col' => '4',
                ),



            )
        );

        return parent::renderForm();
    }
}
```

Also edited the Customer.php in override folder. as below:

```
class Customer extends CustomerCore {

    public $practice_from;

    /** nature of enquiry */
    public $nature_enquiry;

    protected  $definition = array(
        'table' => 'customer',
        'primary' => 'id_customer',
        'fields' => array(
         'nature_enquiry' => array('type' => self::TYPE_HTML, 'validate' => 'isCleanHtml', 'required'=>false,'size' => 65000),

        ),
    );

    public function __construct($id = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($id);
        parent::$definition['practice_from'] = ['type' => parent::TYPE_STRING];
    }
}
```

lastly added my new field to the classes/Customer.php at the bottom of the definition array  as below:

```
public static $definition = array(
    'table' => 'customer',
    'primary' => 'id_customer',
    'fields' => array(
        'secure_key' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isMd5', 'copy_post' => false),
        'lastname' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 255),
        'firstname' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 255),
        'email' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isEmail', 'required' => true, 'size' => 128),
        'passwd' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isPasswd', 'required' => true, 'size' => 60),
        'last_passwd_gen' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'copy_post' => false),
        'id_gender' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId'),
        'birthday' => array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isBirthDate'),
        'newsletter' => array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool'),
        'newsletter_date_add' => array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'copy_post' => false),
        'ip_registration_newsletter' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'copy_post' => false),
        'optin' => array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool'),
        'website' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isUrl'),
        'company' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isGenericName'),
        'siret' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isSiret'),
        'ape' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isApe'),
        'outstanding_allow_amount' => array('type' => self::TYPE_FLOAT, 'validate' => 'isFloat', 'copy_post' => false),
        'show_public_prices' => array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool', 'copy_post' => false),
        'id_risk' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedInt', 'copy_post' => false),
        'max_payment_days' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedInt', 'copy_post' => false),
        'active' => array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool', 'copy_post' => false),
        'deleted' => array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool', 'copy_post' => false),
        'note' => array('type' => self::TYPE_HTML, 'validate' => 'isCleanHtml', 'size' => 65000, 'copy_post' => false),
        'is_guest' => array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool', 'copy_post' => false),
        'id_shop' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId', 'copy_post' => false),
        'id_shop_group' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId', 'copy_post' => false),
        'id_default_group' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'copy_post' => false),
        'id_lang' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId', 'copy_post' => false),
        'date_add' => array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDate', 'copy_post' => false),
        'date_upd' => array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDate', 'copy_post' => false),
        'reset_password_token' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isSha1', 'size' => 40, 'copy_post' => false),
        'reset_password_validity' => array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDateOrNull', 'copy_post' => false),
        'nature_enquiry' => array('type' => self::TYPE_HTML, 'validate' => 'isCleanHtml', 'required'=>false,'size' => 65000),

    ),
);
```

classes/form/CustomerFormatter.php

```
$format['nature_enquiry'] = (new FormField)
    ->setName('nature_enquiry')
    ->setLabel(
        $this->translator->trans(
            'Nature of Business', [], 'Shop.Forms.Labels'
        )
    );
```

Ideally I wanted to know I have missed anything in order to get this working on the live site.

or any documentation for adding a custom field to the registrations form.

PrestaShop -  1.7.0.6

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must avoid editing core codes. overrides is not recommended too. you should try to create a module.

You can use this hooks in your module:

```
public function hookAdditionalCustomerFormFields($params)
{
    //return html of your field
}

public function hookActionSubmitAccountBefore($params)
{
    //process your field posted data
}


public function hookActionAdminCustomersListingFieldsModifier($params)
{
    //show your filed in admin customers list
    $params['fields']['your_new_field'] = array(
        'title' => $this->l('label'),
        'align' => 'center',
    );
}

public function hookActionAdminCustomersFormModifier($params)
{
    dd($params);
    //add your fields
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't looked at your changes in detail, but they look solid at first glance. To keep these changes when updating you will need to "override" these files. See [the official docs on overrides](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/overrides/). It basically consists of creating the appropriate files in the `[prestashop_root_dir]/overrides` directory and rewriting the methods you want to change.

You will also need to delete `[prestashop_root_dir]/app/cache/pro/class_index.php` so the overriden files get loaded.